# Proving gcd(a, a+2) is 1 or 2 for every integer a?

Tags: number-theory

I want to prove $gcd(a, a+2)$ = 1 or 2 for every integer $a$.

I know that (a, a+2) is equal to the least positive value of $ax + (a+2)y$, where $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$. However, I'm a little stuck at this point. I'm thinking I should split apart the problem into two cases, one where $a$ is odd and one where $a$ is even? Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: By the Euclidean algorithm $\,\gcd(a,a\!+\!2) = \gcd(a,2)\ $

Comment: Let $x=-1,y=1$. So $1\le (a,a+2)\le 2$ from which the result follows.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

If integer $d$ divides $a,a+2;$

$d$ will divide $1\cdot(a+2)-1\cdot a$

Th idea is to find a constant eliminating $a$

Comment: Hmmmm, okay I deduced that much -- i.e. $d | 2$. I'm not sure what you mean by "find a constant eliminating a" though...

Comment: @RyanYu, If we derive $d|a,$ the gcd has to be a divisor of $a$

Answer (score 3):

Let $\gcd(a,a+2)=d$. Then $d$ divides $a$ and $a+2$. So $d$ divides $a+(a+2)=2(a+1)$, and $d$ divides $(a+2)-a=2$. Hence $d$ is the common divisor of  $2(a+1)$ and $2$. But:
$$\gcd\!\big(2(a+1),2\big)=2\gcd(a+1,1)=2\cdot1=2$$
So $d$ divides $2$. Hence $d=1$ or $2$.

Comment: Just a small spelling correction: It's not "devices" but "divides". It's also not "devisor" but "divisor".

Answer (score 2):

Consider what happens if 3 divides $a$. What is the next largest integer that 3 divides? What does that tell you about $a+2$?

Now generalise. What if $k>2$ divides $a$?